# WINE - Installed Aion 4.7.1, Graphics not working & buggy text?

Tags: graphics, wine, games, winetricks

So I got Aion to work finally after creating a new 32 bit wineprefix. I installed all the components on the WineHQ page for Aion. But after launching the game and making it to the login screen, nearly everything is screwed up. I took a screenshot...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njc2F.jpg

So all the text is unrecognizable and idk what's going on with the graphics. I installed Aion with Gameforge Live on PlayOnLinux and could play the game for the most part. Is this a problem with my graphics drivers? I'm not using the proprietary drivers right now. But I think I did everything else I was supposed to.